# Reports are blank on win serv 2008 but not on win7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, report, windows-server-2008

I have an asp.net C# application, when building or debuging the app (development enviroment) and if we deploy it to iis 7 on win 7, the reports will show.

However when deploying app on iis on win server 2008 reports will return blank.

Troubleshooting:
Followed instructions provided by the links below - Confirmed

Made sure that reportviewer dlls are installed on machine (win serv 2008 currently working with version 10.0.0.0) - Confirmed

Other applications are already runnin on this server and work perfectly fine - Confirmed

To be honest I have no idea what the issue might be

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
<assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />

</assemblies>
 <httpHandlers>
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
```

**page.Aspx**

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <rsweb:ReportViewer  ID="ReportViewer1"  runat="server"  width="100%" Height="100%" SizeToReportContent="true" AsyncRendering="false">
      </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
```

**Code behind**

```
 private void getReport(ReportViewer report_viewer, string report_path, ReportParameter report_parameter, DataTable sourceTable, DataTable sourceGraph)
    {
        report_viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        report_viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(report_path);
        report_viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        report_viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1 });
        report_viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Table", sourceTable));
        report_viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Graph", sourceGraph));
        report_viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

    }
```

[Reference 1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1388924.aspx?ReportViewer%20showing%20an%20Empty%20report%20on%20Windows%20Server%202008)

[Reference 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a043e1be-9843-4456-ae8d-8b1c8aff979c/report-viewer-shows-blank-page-only-some-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Have you ruled out the data in the database or the connection strings to your databases?

Comment: Yeap, the login page confirms that it is able to access the db. On both win7 and win serv 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no problem with the reports themselves, however as KSib mentioned there was an issue getting the data from the DB. One must be careful when working with dates, especially if the development machine has a different language than the deployment server.